# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null javascript

Tags: javascript

This code should make an element disappear from a list when it is dropped on another element (called cookiemonster)

```js
addEvent(cookiemonster, 'drop', function (e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

  var el = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This means that `el` is null....

Comment: what is the output of `e.dataTransfer.getData('text')`? there seems to be no element by that ID

Comment: It seems there is no element returned by the `document.getElementById()`; what does `e.dataTransfer.getData('text')` return? Does it match an `id` of an element in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an auxiliar variable like this

```
addEvent(cookiemonster, 'drop', function (e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    var el = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
    var aux = el.parentNode;
    aux.removeChild(el);
    return false;
});
```